# angular-google-map: unable to get marker on the map

Tags: ionic-framework, angular-google-maps

I am currently working for ionic app, and need to show a map of a place. I am using angular-google-map, and the map did show in the screen. The problem is I couldn't get the **marker** on the map!
I am really running out of idea on why the **marker** did not show up.

My html code:

```
<div id="map_canvas" ng-controller="mapCtrl">
  <ui-gmap-google-map center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom">
    <ui-gmap-marker coords="marker.coords" idkey="'1'"></ui-gmap-marker>
  </ui-gmap-google-map>
</div>
```

My controllers.js code:

```
.controller('mapCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.map = { center: { latitude: 3.133098, longitude: 101.6816 }, zoom: 16};
  $scope.marker = {coords: { latitude: 3.133098, longitude: 101.6816 } };
});
```

Comment: Do you see any errors in your console?

Comment: No error in console.

Comment: I believe it is an issue with `idkey`. Try to put an id on $scope.marker. Like in the example here : http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/api/marker

Comment: I put in id in `$scope.marker`. Still no marker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by first completely re-install angular-google-maps, and adding the following three lines:

`<script src="lib/lodash/lodash.js"></script>
 <script src="lib/angular-simple-logger/dist/angular-simple-logger.js"></script>
 <script src="lib/angular-google-maps/dist/angular-google-maps.js"></script>`

I've got everything mix-up. Decided to start clean, and paid close attention on error console. Now both marker and map work just fine!